# Post Comments using Jsoup Java

Tags: java, android, post, methods, jsoup

how can I post comment on site using jsoup, if on button set method from javascript
like this:

```
<div class="b-textearea">
                        <textarea rows="3" name="addcomment" id="txtComments" class="fullboxtext"></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="verify" value= "6b43e52744d7570743d8d893e1d11130" />
                        <input type="button" class="but" name="commentpost" onClick="fxSendComments('divComments','txtComments',6469,107169)" />
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup can't emulate an browser.. to get work of calling javascript functions you'll need to use some kind of browser emulator for android or java.